# Taking a day off

Tags: meaning, questions

> Is anyone willing to take a day during the week off?

What does this sentence imply?
I wanted to let employees know that they can take another day off. Please advise if the first sentence is correct.

Comment: Please give your question a more specific, descriptive title. This entire site is about the English Language.

Comment: The sentence doesn't imply anything, it's just a simple question and will be taken literally.

Comment: Just say "You can take another day off if you want". But who wouldn't want to take another day off?

Comment: It's confusing.  Not clear whether your asking for an extra day off, or a day of "not off" in the middle of the week off, or what.

Comment: Check the meaning of "willing" in a dictionary.  It doesn't mean what you think.  If you want to let them know that they can take another day off, then tell them "You can take another day off if you wish."

Answer (score 1):

That sentence doesn't express what you want. If the *day* is the one supposed to be taken off, then keep *off* next to it.

> Is anyone willing to take a day off during the week?

The sentence

> Is anyone willing to take a day during the week off?

is asking if anyone is willing to *take a day*, an action that could be different from the idiomatic *take a day off*. Furthermore, it is asking that if they are willing to do that action *during the week* that is being called *off*, where *off* is being used as an adjective. This is, the *week* is being called worse than usual; unsatisfactory or inadequate, or it is being said that the whole week is the one that is work-free.